# How can I create a video and photo uploading feature on my website using Python and Django?

Tags: django

How can I create a video and photo uploading feature on my website using Python and Django?

I have  using forms,models(file_field) and yet it doesn't render to the front_end

Comment: What have you tried? Your question is too broad so we can barely help you. See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ImageField to upload to the server, make sure you have pillow installed. Your python may just be looking at a wrong path to search for your files. Secondly, you might want to consider your markup code, and make sure that there is space for your video to be uploaded. ie) ,  etc..

Comment: The images has been sorted out.But the videos arent rendering.